# Classic ASP: Dynamic dropdown bases on a radio button selected

Tags: asp-classic

I'm new to Classic ASP. I want to display the list in dropdown based on one of the radio buttons selected.  The database has the column for the Code such as "A" and "O". On the page, I want to display 3 radio buttons as A, O, and All.  A = Apples, O = Oranges and All = Apples and Oranges. Lets say, when the user selected A then the dropdown automatically list all type of apples or selected O then dropdown should list all type of oranges, or All for both. The page should automatically display apples by default.  How do I go about displaying the radio buttons on the page? Do I need JavaScript or use the record set for the radio button selected event? Please help

Comment: Just want to make sure that you are asking about pre .net classic ASP as the term "radio button selected event" tells me this is likely to be ASP.net web forms not Classic ASP, which was written in vbScript and did not have events per say

Comment: Yes, I asked about classic ASP.You are corrected I used the wrong term... confused w/ASP.NET. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

We did stuff like this with javascript arrays. We assigned what we called a DataType to each group of values. For example Apples would have a DataType of 10; Oranges a DataType of 20, Pears would have a DataType of 30 etc. The radio button would have corresponding values. RadioButton.Apple = 10, RadioButton.Orange = 20, RadioButon.Pears = 30, etc.

We would bring back all the data for all datatypes and store it inside a javascript array. We setup onClick or onChange events for the radio buttons and repopulated our dropdows from the javascript arrays depending on the datatype selected in the radio button.

Works like a champ.

Comment: Would you please provide me the JavaScript codes on OnChange? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you could display the radio butttons just with "normal" (static) html

then define the onclick event and make an ajaxrequest to your classic asp site. send back the contents of the dropdown depending on the value of the radio button in json or just html and fill the dropdown via javascript.

links:

[link for JSON](http://json.org/)

[jQuery (which is a cool javascript framework)](http://jquery.com/)

[documentation for jQuery post (ajax request with jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

as you never used json you could try sending the results as html like so:

```
<%
if request.form("act") = "loadDropdown" then
    dim html : html = ""

    select case request.form("which")
        case "A"
            ' load apples


            ' write recordset as html to client
            do while not rs.eof
                html = html & "<option value='" & rs.fields("applename").value & "'>" &     rs.fields("applename").value & "</option>"

                rs.movenext
            loop
            response.write html
        case "O"
            ' load oranges


            ' write recordset as html to client
            do while not rs.eof
                html = html & "<option value='" & rs.fields("applename").value & "'>" & rs.fields("applename").value & "</option>"

                rs.movenext
            loop
            response.write html
        case "all"
            ' load all fruits


            ' write recordset as html to client
            do while not rs.eof
                html = html & "<option value='" & rs.fields("applename").value & "'>" & rs.fields("applename").value & "</option>"

                rs.movenext
            loop
            response.write html
    end select

    response.end
end if
%>
<script>
    function loadDropdown(which) {
        $.post("mySite.asp", { act: "loadDropdown", which: which }, function(data) {

            // fill dropwon with results of ajax:
            $("#myDropdown").html( data )
        });
    }
</script>
<input type="radio" name="fruits" onclick="loadDropdown('A')"> Apples<br>
<input type="radio" name="fruits" onclick="loadDropdown('O')" > Oranges<br>
<input type="radio" name="fruits" onclick="loadDropdown('all')"> All<br>

<select name="myDropdown" id="myDropdown"></select>
```

`

Comment: I never try ajaxrequest/json. If you could provide me the link(s) regarding ajaxrequest/json...examples on how to use it, I'm greatly appreciated. Thanks for the answer! Now, I can start searching for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way with ASP.net is to use the radio button selected event. The down side of this is that it will trigger a complete postback of the page, so the form will appear to flash or re-load.

You can achieve this affect with the [Update Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (available in Visual Studio 2008 onwards). The update panel has its own pros and cons, [outlined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx). The linked article also shows how to use it.

You could also do it all client side, particularly if the combined contents of "Apples and Organges" is not particularly large. Here you could load up an array of Javascript Objects or use [JASON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx) and use that to populate your drop down list.

A not so elegant way to do this client side would be to render three lists to the page as three separate dropdowns and use javascript ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is very powerful here) to display the appropriate list. Server side you would get the select your value from the list determined by the radio button selection.

Comment: I can't do this in ASP.NET because the existing application is in the classic ASP. I'm suppose to add the filter to the existing dropdown by types as mentioned in the radio buttons above. My plan was to use the radio buttons as the filter.  I could use JavaScript on the client side. For the radio buttons, I'm thinking of... onSelect instead of onClick. Do you know where I can find good examples regarding the radio buttons/JavaScript? BTW, thanks! I hope I'm not confusing you from my previous comments.